# Como faço para filtrar consultas do meu banco de dados pelo Python? Usando mysql

Tags: mysql, python, filter

Estou fazendo um sistema de "inventario", nele temos na segunda tela uma tela de pesquisa e a terceira a tela que mostra os resultados da pesquisa. Essa pesquisa é uma pesquisa no banco de dados, mas por enquanto quando aperto em pesquisar ele aparece todos os registros do banco de dados, eu queria saber como faço um filtro de pesquisa. Segue as imagens e o código

[![telapesquisa][1]][1]
[![telaresultado][2]][2]

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore
from telamain import *
import mysql.connector

#Connect to mysql server
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost", 
    user="root", 
    passwd="",
    database="inventario"
)

def chama_telapesquisa():
     
    nome_usuario = telamain.lineEdit.text() 
    senha = telamain.lineEdit_2.text()
    if nome_usuario == "user" and senha == "123" :
        telamain.close()
        telapesquisa.show()
    

def telapesquisa():
    idprodutosc = telapesquisa.lineEdit.text()
    categoriasc = telapesquisa.lineEdit_2.text()
    marcasc = telapesquisa.lineEdit_3.text()
    modelosc = telapesquisa.lineEdit_4.text()
    numseriesc = telapesquisa.lineEdit_5.text()
    localsc = telapesquisa.lineEdit_6.text()
  

def chama_telaresultados():

    
    telapesquisa.close()
    telaresultados.show() 



    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    comando_sql = "SELECT * FROM cpd_room"
    cursor.execute(comando_sql)
    dados_lidos = cursor.fetchall()

    telaresultados.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(dados_lidos))
    telaresultados.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)

    for i in range(0, len(dados_lidos)):
        for j in range(0,8):
            telaresultados.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dados_lidos[i][j])))

def volta_telapesquisa():

    telaresultados.close()
    telapesquisa.show()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
telamain=uic.loadUi("telamain.ui")
telapesquisa = uic.loadUi("telapesquisa.ui")
telaresultados = uic.loadUi("telaresultados.ui")
telapesquisa.pushButton.clicked.connect(chama_telaresultados)
telaresultados.pushButton.clicked.connect(volta_telapesquisa)
telamain.pushButton.clicked.connect(chama_telapesquisa)
telamain.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)


telamain.show()
app.exec()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A36Wh.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVkcZ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está uma possibilidade de uso do Python para fazer pesquisa no banco de dados.

Note que seu código faz uso de comando `"SELECT * FROM cpd_room"` que pede para retornar todos os dados registrados em **cdp_room**. Cabe estudar um pouco mais a linguagem sql pra conseguir fazer coisas mais interessantes.

Dado a grande possibilidades de respostas, fica só esse exemplo pra que vc quebre a cabeça um pouco em como pode melhorar o teu código, de acordo com tuas necessidades.

```
def chama_telaresultados():

    idprodutosc = telapesquisa.lineEdit.text()
    telapesquisa.close()
    telaresultados.show() 



    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    comando_sql = (f"SELECT {idprodutosc} FROM cpd_room;")
    cursor.execute(comando_sql)
    dados_lidos = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Bom dia Carlos! Então, eu ja tinha tentado isso e quebrei minha cabeça mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum, se você conseguir me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato. Pegando esse exemplo seu, meu "idprodutosc" é uma lineEdit da tela de pesquisa correto? Eu queria escrever dentro dessa lineEdit, e o que está sendo escrito la, será filtrado na tela de resultados. Como se fosse:
(ID: 2,
Categoria: Mouse,
Marca: Dell)

E aí tem varios mouses dell, mas quando eu escrevo o numero "2" na lineEdit de 'idprodutosc' ele só aparece o que o ID = 2.

Comment: é pq id é único... certo? ou estou entendendo errado? se for um filtro mais geral o comando_sql teria que conter o código SQL ```comando_sql = (f"SELECT * FROM cpd_room WHERE {idprodutosc};")``` por exemplo... vc pode fazer várias entradas como ```comando_sql = (f"SELECT {idprodutosc} FROM cpd_room WHERE {categoriasc} BETWEEN {numseriesc} AND {numseriesc2};")```